# Getting output from from VS WSL build events

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Visual Studio has a relatively new way of doing Linux builds, using the local WSL system.  This platform toolset is called `WSL_1_0`

What in a remote build was called "Remote Pre-Build Event" is now called "Wsl Pre-Build Event" (in the UI..still Remote whatever in msbuild, apparently) and it works basically the same, but with execution occurring in WSL on the local machine rather than on a linux machine.

Aaaand...any script output seems to be swallowed (vs. running on a remote machine where it was displayed in the build window):

```
1>Target RemotePreBuildEvent:
1>  Invoking 'echo "me : stuff error 567 HELLO"', working directory: '/mnt/s/buildroot/CoreTech/ThirdPartyTools/Encryption/Rijndael/Project/Linux'
1>Target ClCompile:
1>  Starting remote build
```

If I replace this with a script, it is executed..but the output is swallowed.

I've tried redirecting to stderr both within the script and within the command and it seems to change nothing.  I've also adjusted `Tools->Options->Project and Solutions->Build and Run` output verbosity as high as I'm willing to (`Normal`) with no changes.

Anyone have any ideas on solving this?

Answer (score 0):

> I've also adjusted Tools->Options->Project and Solutions->Build and
>   Run output verbosity as high as I'm willing to (Normal) with no
>   changes.

Normally it's recommended to change the Verbosity to `Detailed` and higher to see more details. And this is the only option I know in latest `VS2019 16.3.7` can control the behavior of output log.

So you can change it to Detailed to check if there's more info to be displayed in output window.(For some reason,my configuration fails for the wsl.exe, so I can't test it myself whether this option can work)

And if the `echo` info is still not shown, I guess this scenario is not be supported for now since it's quite a new feature. Just post your feedback in DC as the `Give Us Feedback` in [this document](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c-with-visual-studio-2019-and-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl/) suggests. The team there would look and consider about supporting that. May it makes some help :)

Comment: You can also consider updating the dc report link in your question, members interested in that will help vote it :)